# publish more .net mvc applications with one click in visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, publish

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2012 with more MVC Web Projects. These are standalone modules of a complex system.

I want to have the ability to publish these projects separately, but in the most cases I don't have to publish only one of them. In this cases i want to publish e.g. Project A + Project B + Project C or Project A + Project D etc.

I created already a publish profile for all these projects. With these profiles I can easily publish one project at the time.

Can I somehow configure Visual Studio to run all the selected (configured) publish operations at the same time? Can I publish more than one projects with one click?

Answer (score 0):

Not in Visual Studio, however you can archive it using MSBuild command line.
I will update answer with example later on. short on time.

Comment: Thank you! I am waiting for your explanation.